# Add function to output error string on Google Test assertions

Tags: c++, googletest

I would like to have a function I can stream to an `ASSERT_`.  Something I could use like this:

```
ASSERT_EQ(std::remove(someFile), 0) << displayErrStr(__LINE__);
```

And the output would be

```
test.cc:32: Failure
      Expected: std::remove(someFile)
      Which is: -1
To be equal to: 0
Error at line 32: Directory not empty
```

I can do it by adding `<< "Error at line " << __LINE__ << ": " << strerror(errno)` to every relevant line but this is more verbose than I want.

I assume this is possible but I'm not a C++ expert.